# Python strange syntaxis

Tags: python, arrays, for-loop, numpy, neural-network

I have been learning about ANN but the book I'm reading has examples in Python. The problem is that I have never written in Python and these lines of code are too hard for me to understand:

```
sizes = [3,2,4]
self.weights = [np.random.randn(y, x) 
                    for x, y in zip(sizes[:-1], sizes[1:])]
```

I read some things about it and found out that the `randn()` function returns an array with `y` elements and `x` dimensions populated with random numbers between 0 and 1. `zip()` connects two arrays into one. `sizes[:-1]` returns the last element and `sizes[1:]` return the array without its first element.

But with all of this I still can't explain to myself what would this generate.

Comment: ``sizes[:-1]`` returns the array up until (i.e. not including) its last element. ``sizes[-1]`` returns the last element of the array.

Comment: Yeah I figured that out because of the other answers

Answer (score 5, accepted):

`sizes[:-1]` will return the sublist `[3,2]` (that is, all the elements except the last one).

`sizes[1:]` will return the sublist `[2,4]` (that is, all the elements except the first one).

`zip([a,b], [c,d])` gives `[(a,c), (b,d)]`.

So zipping the two lists above gives you `[(3,2), (2,4)]`

The construction of weights is a [list comprehension](https://docs.python.org/3/tutorial/datastructures.html#list-comprehensions). Therefore this code is equivalent to

```
weights = []

for x,y in [(3,2), (2,4)]:
       weights.append(np.random.randn(y, x))
```

So the final result would be the same as

```
[ np.random.randn(2,3), 
  np.random.randn(4,2) ]
```

Comment: Thanks a lot for explaining. It turns out I was mistaken about what :-1 does and what zip does.

Comment: @ChadSimmons: I've taken the freedom to add a few details to your answers, to make it more clear. Feel free to revert my edit if you don't like it.

Comment: This answer is incorrect. ``for x, y in [(3,2), (2,4)]`` is not the same as ``for x in [3,2]:\n\tfor y in [2,4]:``. The first uses tuple expansion to set x and y to 3 and 2 respectively for the first iteration of the loop, and 2 and 4 respectively for the second iteration. That means that there is a total of two iterations. The second (nested for-loops), has a total iteration count of 4. Additionally, you mistakenly computed ``np.random.randn(x, y)`` instead of ``np.random.randn(y, x)``. Therefore, the output of this code should be ``[np.random.randn(2, 3), np.random.randn(4, 2)]``.

Comment: fixed the x, y transpose

Comment: @ChadSimmons Your answer is still wrong. Try running your code and the OPs code, and compare the output. You: ``[np.random.randn(2,3), np.random.randn(4,3), np.random.randn(2,2), np.random.randn(4,2)]``. OP: ``[np.random.randn(2,3), np.random.randn(4,2)]``.

Answer (score 2):

a lot is going on here.

let's decompose that expression: as you said `zip` will create a list of tuples containing each element of `sizes` and it's successor (except for the last one)

The comprehension list `[ ... for x, y in zip(..)]` works as follows: the tuple is exploded in the variables `x` and `y` and those are passed onto `np.random.randn` to create a list of random matrices.

These matrices are characterized by having the first dimension (rows) long as specified by each element of `sizes` and the second dimension (columns) long as the following element.

Interestingly, the matrices have compatible dimensions to be multiplied to each other in that sequence, but I guess that this is not the purpose. The purpose of each matrix in the `weights` list is to specify the weights that are between fully connected layers of neurons. Good luck! Seems a fun project!

### Post Scriptum

since you are a beginner: you can add the `import pdb; pdb.set_trace()` statement anywhere in your code to get a breakpoint. Then you can just copy and paste different parts of any expression to see what comes out.
For example:

`ipdb> print sizes
[3, 2, 4]
ipdb> print sizes[:-1]
[3, 2]
ipdb> print sizes[1:]
[2, 4]
ipdb> print zip(sizes[:-1], sizes[1:])
[(3, 2), (2, 4)]
ipdb> print [np.random.randn(y, x) for x, y in zip(sizes[:-1], sizes[1:])]
[array([[ 0.25933943,  0.59855688,  0.49055744],
       [ 0.94602292, -0.8012292 ,  0.56352986]]), array([[ 0.81328847, -0.53234407],
       [-0.272656  , -1.24978881],
       [-1.2306653 ,  0.56038948],
       [ 1.15837792,  1.19408038]])]`

Comment: Thanks for explaining. Yeah it's a fun project. A little too hard for me but I'm handling it for now. Also the numbers (3,2,4) were just for clearer explanation I chose them randomly.

Answer (score 2):

Let's break this up into chunks:

---

```
self.weights = [some junk]
```

is going to be a list comprehension.  Meaning, do the `some junk` stuff and you'll end up with a list of elements from that. Usually these look like so:

```
self.weights = [some_func(x) for x in a_list]
```

This is the equivalent of:

```
self.weights = []
for x in a_list:
    self.weights.append(some_func(x))
```

---

```
zip(a, b)
```

Will piecewise combine the elements of `a` and `b` into tuple pairs:

```
(a1, b1), (a2, b2), (a3, b3), ...
```

---

```
for x, y in zip(a, b):
```

This iterates through that tuple pairs talked about above

---

```
sizes[:-1]
```

This is stating to get all the elements of list `sizes` except the **last** item (`-1`).

```
sizes[1:]
```

This is stating to get the all the elements of list `sizes` except the **first** item.

---

So, finally piecing this all together you get:

```
self.weights = [np.random.randn(y, x) for x, y in zip(sizes[:-1], sizes[1:])]
```

Which is a list comprehension iterating through the tuple pairs of first sizes from 2nd item to last and second from 1st item to next to last, create a random number based on those two parameters, then append to a list that is stored as `self.weights`

Answer (score 0):

This code generates a list and assignes it to the self.weights attribute (this is maybe inside a class? That would explain the self). The second line is a list comprehension. It generates a list, applying the function randn to pairs of variables (x, y)